# Слетели шрифты на сайте с установленной cms WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, шрифты

Слетели иконки (шрифты) [на сайте](http://leader-style.com/) установленном wordpress движок.
До сегодня слетали один раз после внесения правок в стилях. Помог плагин SSL, который заменяет http ссылки на https, а в этот раз не помогает. В Базе все ссылки проставленные https. Какие методы решения ещё можно попробовать?

Comment: Так вам плагин SSL помог же или нет?

Comment: @АннаМатвеева помог первый раз. А в этот раз не помогает

Comment: Вы можете вспомнить какие действия совершали до того как слетел шрифт иконок? Сейчас у вас на сайте рабочие шрифты для текста, а шрифт с иконками внутри - пустой

Comment: посмотрите в css файлах темы. Может там где то стоит через http.

Comment: в этих файлах обращение без привязки к http/https

Comment: да, там обращение к относительным ссылкам

Comment: Вопрос решился, был перенесён иконочный шрифт из подпапки в основную подпапку, прописав им путь на основную папку - не сработало, после перенесения папки на своё законное место всё встало на места

Comment: Удалите плагин. Через wp cli замените все ссылки с http на https и будет вам счастье. Если будут проблемы, тогда уже ищите в вашей теме